# Vue component in laravel - databinding not responsive

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, vue.js

My first Vue.js component in laravel drives me crazy. I need to make a binding between a component and an array in javascript. As there are elements added in the array I need to make it responsive but all articles related to this topic do not help me at all. It seems that I just do not hit my target variable.

My app.js (it contains some test data to verify that my component ist working in priciple and it does):

```js
Vue.component('veg-bed-table', require('./components/VegBedTable.vue'));

var vegbed = new Vue({
    el: '#vegbed',
    data: function () {
        return {
            bedcomposition: [{id:2222, picref:234, plant:{name:1234}},{id:2223, picref:234, plant:{name:1234}}]
        }
    }
});
```

My VegBedTable.vue:

```html
<template>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">Image</th>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="plant in plants">
                <th scope="row">{{ plant.id }}</th>
                <td><img height="18px" :src="plant.picref"></td>
                <td>{{ plant.plant.name }}</td>
            </tr>               
        </tbody>    
    </table>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props:[
                'plants'
            ],
            
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

The call of the component in the blade looks like this:

```html
            <div id="vegbed">
                <veg-bed-table v-bind:plants="bedcomposition"></veg-bed-table>
            </div>
```

After loading the page everything looks fine, the component shows the two lines in the inital data. But when I try to assign the real data by calling a js function I get a warning:

[Vue warn]: Cannot set reactive property on undefined, null, or primitive value: undefined

followed by an error:
TypeError: right-hand side of 'in' should be an object, got undefined[Weitere Informationen]

both in the line of the Vue.set....

```js
function addPlant(pref, plantsgroup, plant) {
    data.push({id:uuidv4(), x:50,y:50 ,picref:pref+'.svg',picsize:40, plant:plant, plantsgroup:plantsgroup});

    Vue.set(vegbed.bedcomposition, data);

    
    updateBedContent();
}
```

When I try

```js
Vue.set(vegbed, "bedcomposition", data);
```

instead I get no reaction at all.

So I have the impression I have a context/namespace issue but after 3hours reading and trial&error I'm really frustrated. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set -- Vue.set takes Object, Key, Value -- doesn't look like that's what you're doing

Comment: You are right, that was my last silly trial. I've tried also Vue.set(vegbed, "bedcomposition", data); In this case I get no error, but it shows no reaction at all

Comment: Where are you calling `addPlant`? Why isn't that associated with one of your components?

Comment: I'm calling addplant in my blade. I want to update an array that is created there already to feed a dynamic svg (d3.js). The vue component should be used for a data table below.

Comment: I don't use Laravel, but if it's referencing part of your vue data, it should be a method on your component. See if something like this works: https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/events.html -- skip down to the inline statements section